# Elastic Search Spring Data not setting FieldType Nested

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, spring-boot-starter

I'm working with spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch version 2.7.3, ElasticSearch version 8.7.1.

I have a field, B, annotated as `@Field(type = FieldType.Nested)` in class A.

I create an index on class A with:

`elasticsearchTemplate.indexOps(A.class).create();`

However, in the created index for A, field B (an object) does not have type="nested".

Appreciate any insights anyone may have.

This was working with previous versions.

Comment: According to the documentation, Spring Boot 2.7 only supports up to ES 7.17. In order to use ES 8.7, [you need Spring boot 3.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/5.1.2/reference/html/#preface.versions)

Comment: Good point, however, I tried this with version 7.17 as well. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOperations.create()` does not write the mapping.

You have to either create a Mapping `Document` by yourself and call `IndexOperations.putMapping(mapping)` or use `IndexOperations.createWithMapping()`

Comment: I tried createWithMapping, same results. The objects I am persisting are of type @Document . All other fields in the Class are saved correctly with the type field. The only fields that are not showing the type field are the nested fields. The issue is that many of my existing queries are using the nested query interface and are failing due to this.

Comment: Please provide a compilable, runnable example that demonstrates this.

Comment: createWithMapping did the job. My previous reply to you was due to some other actions that caused the mapping to be incorrect. Thanks for your help!